# Helm Kubernetes MongoDB authentification

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

How can we authenticate to a mongodb database created by helm stable/mongo chart (from another pod in the same cluster)?

- The "one pod url" `mongodb://user:password@mongodb:27017/dbname` does not work because we have to authenticate to the admin pod
- According to mongo documentation, we should use something like :
  `mongodb://user:password@mongodb-1,mongodb-2,mongodb-3:27017/dbname`
  but the chart only creates one service ?!

I tried also to add `?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0` at the url but authentication still fails..

Answer (score 3):

I managed to connect with the following url (only as root) :
`mongodb://root:<root_password>@mongodb.mongodb:27017/<db_name>?authSource=admin&replicaSet=rs0`
with the `--authenticationDatabase admin` of the `NOTES.txt` converted to `authSource=admin` url parameter

Answer (score 0):

Using the `stable/mongodb` chart and enabling the `replicaSet` option, you should connect to the service hostname `<deployment fullname>-mongodb` using the `"root"` user and `mongodbRootPassword` provided password using the `--authenticationDatabase admin` option (or setting `authSource=admin` in the connection URL). Example:

```sh
kubectl exec -it deployname-mongodb-primary-0 -- mongo dbname -u root -p rootpassword --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Intstead, if you set `mongodbUsername`, `mongodbPassword` and `mongodbDatabase`, you can connect as non-root user to the configured database; in this case, you should skip the `--authenticationDatabase` (or `authSource=admin`) option. Example:

```sh
kubectl exec -it deployname-mongodb-primary-0 -- mongo -u username -p userpassword
```